# Biblatex: Change the subentries' delimiter in references from semicolon to period

Tags: biblatex, delimiters

I'm using LuaLaTeX and BibLaTeX to write a report but have a problem as the title.

I want to change the red-marked semicolon in the below picture to period but I cannot find how to.

[image]

Here's the MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,subentry,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}

A\autocite{foo}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant punctuation command here is `\entrysetpunct`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,subentry,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\addperiod\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
A\autocite{set,stdmodel}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Herrmann, W. A.; Öfele, K.; Schneider, S. K.; Herdtweck, E.; Hoffmann, S. D. Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. 2006, 45, 3859–3862. (b) Aksın, Ö.;]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I got an ideal format!